# How to change settings in Splice?

Tags: settings

I just installed the game "Splice" for ubuntu 12.10 from the Humble Bundle (via the software center)...but the game starts up in a windowed resolution that goes over both of my monitors.

How do you get to the settings either in-game or via the file system? (I can't find either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the README (in `/opt/splice`), you can toggle full screen by hitting Ctrl+F.

You can also specify a resolution by doing the following in a terminal:

```
cd /opt/splice
./Splice resolution=[width]x[height] #eg 1280x720
```

You could also change the launcher for it to launch it with the resolution flag, making it so you don't have to use a terminal to launch.

Now I've just got to figure out why video isn't working on my installation...

Comment: Did you figure it out?  I get a sound + a black screen.

Comment: splice got updated with the software updater so now it's working!! yay! no more black screen!!

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> didn't worked for me. But <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> switches to fullscreen resolution.

Comment: while superlinkx's answer is good I think this one is the correct one! ON POINT

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to configure this via a preferences file in this [post on a steam forum](http://steamcommunity.com/app/209790/discussions/0/828925849248262191/#c828925849547093448).

In `.config/unity3d/Cipher Prime Studios, Inc./Splice/prefs`, modify the `Screenmanager Resolution Width` and `Screenmanager Resolution Height` values to whatever is required (for some reason the default was 2880x900).